# Fixing mistakes reading logs

Tags: apache

I have huge 1 GB log file. As I know, it shows errors in my site. But I absolutely don't get it.

I have lots of rows like this:

> 8x.xxx.45.10x (my ip) - - [04/Feb/2011:09:59:48 -0500] "GET /post?slaps=bbrfd HTTP/1.1" 404 278 "http://mywebsite.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/9.0.597.86 Safari/534.13"

What does it mean?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You might just need something like a [graphical log viewer](http://download.cnet.com/Apache-Log-Viewer/3000-2381_4-10795987.html).

Comment: No idea. Works for me. Try a different google result then: http://www.google.com/search?q=Apache+error+log+viewer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That entry indicates that a request for `/post?slaps=bbrfd` on your site was not found (404). The request came from your IP, transferred 278 bytes of data (the 404 error page's contents). The link that couldn't be found was clicked on `mywebsite.com`, and the rest is how the browser identified itself. The two dashes are for "remote username", and "username as logged into the site". The remote username is VERY rarely present, as it requires the remote site running identd and would slow down your site massively.

Comment: where I can found table or something which shows what code means and I could be able to detect errors?

Comment: The standard error codes are in the HTTP spec (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_status_codes has a good version of it). The errors you'd want to check for are generally 404 and anything in the 5xx range. 404 is missing pages. 5xx is serious internal errors. 2xx is "a-ok", 3xx can be ignored unless you've got an infinite redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an access log file from Apache. Nothing to do with PHP or MySQL. Looks the user got a 404 page when trying to access /post?slaps=bbrfd

This would suggest the URL does not exist.